# Select2 Query service is null

Tags: angular, typescript, scope

I would customize the search for my select2 dropdown.
After writing 3 character in the search field i would execute a service call with these search params.

When I select the dropdown it shows me the error TypeError (Cannot read property 'machineService' of null)
The service is initialized before the getSelectOptions-Method is called.

**HTML:**

```
<select2 id="inputMachine"
         [data]="machinesModel.data"
         [options]="machinesModel.options"
         [width]="'100%'"
         [disabled]="machinesModel.isDisabled()"
         (valueChanged)="machinesModel.onValueChanged($event); onSelectedMachinesChanged($event)">
</select2>
```

**Component:**

```
protected getSelectOptions(placeholder: string) {
return {
  allowClear: false,
  placeholder: this.translate.instant(placeholder),
  multiple: true,
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  theme: 'bootstrap',
  query: function (options) {
    this.machineService.findProjections(options.term).subscribe(
      machines => {
        this.setMachines(machines);
        options.callback(this.machinesModel.data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Could not load machines: ', error);
      }
    );
  }
};
}
```

Has someone any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope issue.

Usea fat arrow to get rid of that.

```js
protected getSelectOptions(placeholder: string) {
  return {
    allowClear: false,
    placeholder: this.translate.instant(placeholder),
    multiple: true,
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    theme: 'bootstrap',
    query: (options) => {
      this.machineService.findProjections(options.term).subscribe(
        machines => {
          this.setMachines(machines);
          options.callback(this.machinesModel.data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Could not load machines: ', error);
        }
      );
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: It works, but now I have the problem, that the search is cleared when i typed the second character. And also the minimumInputLength option is ignored

Comment: That's another issue and your code doesn't allow me to see why (and in case that wasn't clear enough, it means make another question : 1 question per topic, for imporved readability).

Answer (score 0):

When using `function () {}` the `this` keyword will point to the context of the function itself. As the service is defined outside, it will not be known within this scope. Before arrow functions, you had to do this;

```
var that = this;
{
 // ...
 query: function (options) {
    that.machineService.findProjections(options.term).subscribe();
 }
 // ...
}
```

Using ES6 arrow function however (`=>`), that's not required anymore. They use what's called *lexical scoping*. With arrow functions, the scope will not change so `this` will still refer to the originating context.

```
query: (options) => this.machineService.findProjections(options.term).subscribe()
```